# Django remote server authentication

Tags: django, authentication

I have an environment where multiple virtual machines are deployed throughout a network, but all should authenticate through a centralized cloud based server. Both the VMs and the cloud server have django apps the user can connect to. I am trying to figure out the best way to build this system while leveraging the django login/auth system as much as possible.

Is a [django authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-authentication-backends) on the centralized server suitable for this purpose, or is some other approach needed? If possible, how do you get the VM to point to the centralized server to perform the authorization process through a django login?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to share userdata (e.g. profiles) between these applications or is it just for authentication?

Comment: I just want the cloud system to return a boolean result if the account is valid or not (no other information sharing is required).

Comment: I guess installing a centrally reachable LDAP server would be a pretty neat solution. Only serious drawback is this LDAP server would be read-only from your Django projects.